# How to write a function that acts on second element of each list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm trying to write a simple function that accept coordinate inputs,i.e. $\{\{x1,y1\},\{x2,y2\},...,\{xn,yn\}\}$ but will only work on $y$'s, outputting a list of values that are square of $y$'s, i.e. $\{y1^2,y2^2,\cdots,yn^2\}$.

My function:

[image: fun]

I know my syntax must be wrong but I don't know how to fix it. I would really appreciate any help from you guys!

Comment: What about `fun[list_] := list[[All, 2]]^2`?

Comment: The problem is that you're matching `list` to the sequence of elements of the outer list rather than the outer list itself. I think you meant to use the pattern `list : {__}` instead (though `list : {__List}` would probably be even better).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you! It works!

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Do you mean that I was actually targeting 2 elements $\{2,4\},\{3,5\}$to be input to the Part function? And by doing `list:{_}`, I would be targeting $\{\{2,4\},\{3,5\} \}$?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit or simply `list_List`

Comment: @WeiShanNg Yes, the pattern `{list__}` matches `list` to `Sequence[{2,4}, {3,5}]` which is why `Part` gives such a strange error message. The pattern `list : {__}` matches `list` to `{{2,4}, {3,5}}`.
@Roman Of course that pattern also works. It's just less robust against filtering out illegal lists.

Comment: @WeiShanNg You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a matching pattern that ensures that the function only works on lists that have the right dimensions:

```
fun[list : {{_, __}..}] := list[[All, 2]]^2
```

This function will not evaluate for lists that do not have an `All, 2` part:

```
fun[{1, 2, 3}]
fun[{{1}, {2}, {3}}]
fun[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

> Out[59]= fun[{1, 2, 3}]
>
> Out[60]= fun[{{1}, {2}, {3}}]
>
> Out[61]= {4, 16}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}} /. {x_, y_} -> y^2

(*  {y1^2, y2^2, y3^2}  *)
```

Have fun!